# Select text from multiple textboxes simultaneously

Tags: c#, textbox

i have 10 textboxes and i need to select text from each one of them.
The problem is that i cant select text from multiple textboxes. 
Is there any solution for this problem  my code is.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createTextBoxes(10);

        ((TextBox)textBoxes[0]).Select(1, 4);
        ((TextBox)textBoxes[1]).Select(1, 4); // <- it will not select text 
        ((TextBox)textBoxes[2]).Select(1, 4); // same here
    }
    Control[] textBoxes;
    private void createTextBoxes(int cnt)
    {
        textBoxes = new Control[cnt];
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Name = i.ToString();
            tb.Location = new Point(5, 5 + 14 * i);
            tb.Size = new Size(600, 20);
            tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            tb.Text = "sample text" + i.ToString();
            textBoxes[i] = tb;
            this.Controls.Add(tb);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain it is not selecting the text in the 2nd text box? is it possible the text is selected you just don't see it as selected since the control is not in focus? What is the purpose of the selection?

Comment: i trying to creat rectangular text selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the HideSelection property of the texboxes to false.  They will maintain selection after losing focus.

Comment: So sorry TextBox has HideSelection property only in WinForms but not WPF :(

Answer (score 1):

Only one control can have a "Focus" at a time... you can't select (ie:highlight) text of multiple controls.

I also just tested by adding a button to the form and posted your 3 "select" snippets there too... nothing showed highlighted.  However, when I did a TAB through each control, the first 3 respectfully showed the highlighted section.  When I tabbed through the rest, the entire field of the rest of the textboxes were fully selected.

Or are you really trying to accomplish something else...

Comment: i trying to creat rectangular text selection

Answer (score 1):

The text is selected you just can't see it cause of focus.
I ran your code and after doing so tabbed through the controls. The first 3 are selected as specified.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly not working because even though you've added the TextBox instances to the Form, they have not yet been displayed.  Until they are displayed and initially rendered it's likely not possible to initiate a selection on them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does, the problem is that the other 2 of your textboxes ([1] and [2]) don't have focus. Only one control can have focus at a time. If you hit tab to give focus to the next TextBox, you'll see the text selected.